# Regular expression to get a string between two strings where the last string can also be 'end of string'

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I intend to extract a URL search parameter value using a regular expression in plain [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). The parameter can be in any order in the search query.

So is there a better approach than ?

```js
const query1 = '?someBoolean=false&q=&location=&testParam=dummy_value&testParam2=dummy_value2&requiredParam=requiredValue';

const query2 = '?someBoolean=false&q=&location=&testParam=dummy_value&testParam2=dummy_value2&requiredParam=requiredValue&someMoreParam=dummy_value2';

let requiredParam = query1.match(/requiredParam=(.*?)$/) || [];
console.log('Using regex "/requiredParam=(.*?)$/"');
console.log(`For Query1: result = ${requiredParam[1]}`);

requiredParam = query2.match(/requiredParam=(.*?)&/) || [];
console.log('Using regex "/requiredParam=(.*?)&/"');
console.log(`For Query2: result = ${requiredParam[1]}`);


console.log('Combining both regex "/requiredParam=(.*?)(&|$)/"');
requiredParam = query1.match(/requiredParam=(.*?)(&|$)/) || [];
console.log(`For Query1: result = ${requiredParam[1]}`);
requiredParam = query2.match(/requiredParam=(.*?)(&|$)/) || [];
console.log(`For Query2: result = ${requiredParam[1]}`);
```

Edit:

My constraints:

- Browser compatibility including IE 9
- Using only vanilla javascript

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. After getting an answer you are not allowed to change your code anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). See the section _What should I not do?_ on [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) would make things significantly easier:

```js
const query1 = '?someBoolean=false&q=&location=&testParam=dummy_value&testParam2=dummy_value2&requiredParam=requiredValue';
const query2 = '?someBoolean=false&q=&location=&testParam=dummy_value&testParam2=dummy_value2&requiredParam=requiredValue&someMoreParam=dummy_value2';

const params1 = new URLSearchParams(query1);
const params2 = new URLSearchParams(query2);

console.log(`For Query1: result = ${params1.get('requiredParam')}`);
console.log(`For Query2: result = ${params2.get('requiredParam')}`);
```

It's supported natively in the vast majority of browsers, but not all. For the rest, [here's a polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill). It's better not to re-invent the wheel when you don't need to, and it's good when you're able to use a standard API (with examples and documentation and Stack Overflow answers about it, etc).

As a side note - when using regular expressions, I'd recommend using capture groups only when necessary. If all you need to do is group some tokens together logically (like for a `|` alternation), non-capturing groups should be preferred. That is, if URLSearchParams didn't exist, better to do `(?:&|$)` than `(&|$)`. Reserve capturing groups for when you need to save and use the captured result somewhere - otherwise, non-capturing groups are more appropriate, less expensive, and require less cognitive overhead.

If you had to go the regex route, another slight improvement would be to use a negative character class instead of lazy repetition. In the pattern, you have:

```
(.*?)(&|$)
```

Lazy repetition [is *slow*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444/my-regex-is-matching-too-much-how-do-i-make-it-stop#comment93020571_22457); it forces the engine to advance one character at a time, then check the rest of the pattern for a match, and repeat until the match is found. Since you know that the capture group will not contain any `&`s, better to match anything but `&`s:

```
([^&]*)
```

Once you do that, you don't even need the final `(&|$)` or `(?:&|$)` due to the greedy repetition.

Comment: This solution would have otherwise made my life easy but I have a strict constraint of using 'plain js' and nothing else and so can't use `URLSearchParams` from compatibility point of view  

Comment: If compatibility is the issue, that's what the polyfill is for - and the polyfill *is* written in plain JS. You can see the source code here if you're curious: https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill/blob/master/index.js For professional development, don't be afraid to heavily rely on polyfills (and Babel), they make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

### Bug with variable declarations

The keywords `const` and `let` are only supported (partially) by IE 11<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility)</sup> <sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility)</sup>.

I don't have IE 9 but I do have IE 11 and set the Document mode to IE 9.

[image: IE emulation mode]

Running the first line in a sandbox on jsBin.com :

```
const query1 = '?someBoolean=false&q=&location=&testParam=dummy_value&testParam2=dummy_value2&requiredParam=requiredValue';
```

led to an error in the console:

[image: IE emulation error]

In order to properly support IE 9 users, use `var` instead of `const` and `let`.

Comment: I have not used `const` and `let` in my actual implementation and only here in the sample code snippet. I will edit the code snippet here as well.

Comment: Unfortunately after getting an answer you are not allowed to change your code anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. See the section _What should I not do?_ on [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information

Comment: I added an `edit` note to the question too. I assumed that editing is allowed with the `disclosure`.